# Elasticsearch: Why is my query returning too many results?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm querying `http://elasticsearch.myserver.net:9200/my_index/foo/` with the following query:

```
{
"query": {
    "ids": {
      "type": "foo",
      "values": [
        "fff",
        "bar",
        "baz"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting a response with 12 hits, which is the total number of items of type foo in my index, rather than three, which is the number I requested. I'm making this query by typing it into the "any request" tab of elasticsearch head. What is going on?

Update:

I've also tried

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "ids": {
            "type": "programme",
            "values": [
              "fff",
              "330930",
              "200005"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

with the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If using the Any Request tab in head, make sure you have the dropdown request method set to "POST".  If you have the "GET" method selected it may return all results similar to what you are seeing.

[image]

Comment: That was the problem that ate my whole morning. Solved. Thank you!