# elasticsearch-head nothing to see in browser

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-head

First step in the bigdata world, trying to be confortable with elasticsearch.

I found some nice tutorial and they ask me to install the plugin head.
When I creat my index everything going nice (from Sense plugin on Chrome)

```
 POST /gil/tuto/
{
    "title": "Tuto 1",
    "categorie": "Tuto Elasticsearch ",
    "tag": ["Elasticsearch", "tuto", "ES"],
    "duration": 42
}
```

Doing a GET return a json as excepted.

With head plugin I can see my index but in the browser tab I see nothing, nada, rien du tout.

I reinstall everything from scratch but I still get the problem.

Any idea how to fix this ?

EDIT :

The problem come from the _type.
From the sense or head plugin :
If I try to `GET POST or DELETE /XXX`, It works.
If I try to `GET POST or DELETE /XXX/YYY/ZZZ`, It works.

But If I try to `GET POST or DELETE /XXX/YYY` I have an error.

I think the browser tab use a GET on every _type to load the data.

Something wrong happen with the _type of my _index.

I erase every _index I have. Create a new one. Same trouble.

Comment: What do you see on the left of the Browser tab (i.e. index and types)? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: Yes for sure !
http://imgur.com/a/K73Vg
(I don't know the policy about posting image on SO, hope it works !)

Comment: What happens when you go to "Autres requêtes" and run a `GET /gil/tuto`?

Comment: Did you enabled CORS in Elasticsearch ?

Comment: Are you by any chance running a search on "Any Request" tab? Because even though the manual says "GET", you should search using "POST", it's a quirk of head plugin.

Comment: @Val : http://imgur.com/a/VoTzY

Comment: @Vineeth : Last week I made my first install... Everything worked without enabled anything special. I don't know what is CORS so if you can be more specific thanks.

Comment: @Beowulfenator : POST create a new index right ? But I need a GET to receive the data ?

Comment: @Ragnar - add this in elasticsearch.yml file (  http.cors.enabled: true )

Comment: @VineethMohan : I add it, no change.

Comment: What do you see in firebug ?

Comment: Answer to POST/GET problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363223/why-post-and-not-get-in-elasticsearch-head-ui-any-request

Comment: @Beowulfenator : Yes you right thank you. That's why I have this warning in Sens plugin, but still get the good answer.
http://imgur.com/r544Zb2

Comment: I can GET /gil/tuto/AVDYCBPiYMnO1zW7Qffm or /gil/ but not /gil/tuto/ look like my type isn't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out why Head doesn't act all the tutorials out there !
I have installed ES2.0, all the tutorial were made with < ES2.0.

Also the head plugin seems to not be working well with this version.
Someone advice me about the plugin kopf

```
bin/plugin install lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf
```

Looking good (AngulasJS/Botstrap/Material Design like) and working good too.